# Sender can send but the receiver not receing amount, and also I can't make it work for USDC

Tags: web3.js, spl-token, solana-cli, js, usdc

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm encountering a few challenges with a transaction, and I'd appreciate your insights.

1. **Problem with Transaction Signature:**
   I'm receiving the signature from the sender, and the amount is deducted, but the receiver doesn't seem to receive the funds. Any suggestions on how to ensure a successful transfer?
2. **SPLToken for USDC Issue:**
   I'm facing difficulties in sending transactions using SPLToken for USDC. Has anyone else encountered similar problems or has insights on resolving this issue?
3. **Private Key Permissions:**
   I understand that I don't have permission to access the payer's private key. However, it's crucial for the transaction. As a workaround, I'm considering using the receiver's private key. Any thoughts on this approach or alternative methods for signing transactions without the private key, especially for USDC transfers?

Your expertise is highly valued, and I look forward to any guidance or solutions you can provide. Thank you!

```
async function processPayment(toWallet, fromWallet1, amount) {
    const SystemProgram = solanaWeb3.SystemProgram;
    const Transaction = solanaWeb3.Transaction;
    const provider = getProvider();
    const mintRequester = await provider.publicKey;
    const connection = await establishConnection();
  
    const secretKey = '4Tsg......'; // secret key
    const secretKeyArray = from_b58(secretKey, base58_chars);
    const secretKeyUint8Array = Uint8Array.from(secretKeyArray);

    let fromWallet = Keypair.fromSecretKey(secretKeyUint8Array);
    console.log("towallet", toWallet.publicKey)
    console.log("fromWallet", fromWallet.publicKey)
    const mint = await  Token.createMint(
      connection,
      fromWallet,
      fromWallet.publicKey,
      null,
      9,
      splToken.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
    );

  

    
    usdtoSolana(amount)
    .then((amountSolana) => {
      console.log(`${amount} USD is equivalent to ${amountSolana} Solana`);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });

    // let mint = new splToken.Token(
    //   connection, fromWallet.publicKey, splToken.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, fromWallet
    // );

    // Get the token account of the fromWallet Solana address, if it does not exist, create it
    const fromTokenAccount = await mint.getOrCreateAssociatedAccountInfo(
      fromWallet.publicKey
    );

    //get the token account of the toWallet Solana address, if it does not exist, create it
    const toTokenAccount = await mint.getOrCreateAssociatedAccountInfo(
      toWallet
    );

    // Minting 1 new token to the "fromTokenAccount" account we just returned/created
    await mint.mintTo(
      fromTokenAccount.address,
      fromWallet.publicKey,
      [],
      1000000000
    );
 

    // Add token transfer instructions to transaction
    const transaction = new solanaWeb3.Transaction().add(
      splToken.Token.createTransferInstruction(
        splToken.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        fromTokenAccount.address,
        toTokenAccount.address,
        fromWallet.publicKey,
        [],
        10000
      )
    );
    const signature = await connection.sendTransaction(transaction, [
      fromWallet,
    ]);
    // var signature =  await solanaWeb3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction, [toWallet]);
    console.log("SIGNATURE", signature);
    console.log("SUCCESS");

  }

  async function establishConnection(cluster = 'devnet') {
    const endpoint = solanaWeb3.clusterApiUrl(cluster);
    const connection = new Connection(endpoint, 'confirmed');
    const version = await connection.getVersion();
    console.log('Connection to cluster established:', endpoint, version);

    return connection;
  }

  const getProvider = () => {
    if ('phantom' in window) {
      const provider = window.phantom?.solana;

      if (provider?.isPhantom) {
        return provider;
      }
    }

    window.open('https://phantom.app/', '_blank');
  };
```

Comment: The code you've shown will create a new token mint, and won't send any of it to any wallet. Check out the rest of the steps in the docs here to see how to mint some to a recipient wallet: https://spl.solana.com/token#example-creating-your-own-fungible-token

Answer (score 1):

first of all, **never show your private key to anyone**, i'm able to import your wallet in my phantom with what you showed. I could drain everything in it. So, create a new wallet and never use this one again.

then, i'm not sure about what you are trying to do ? can you explain it first ?

Comment: This is test key and an account will not be used in future

Comment: ok, but even in that case it's better to not do it, we have to show the best practices :)
and so, what are you trying to perform ?

Comment: My first issue is I am sending  solana from one account to another  solana  is getting out from the sender  wallet, but the receiver not receiving

Comment: Second  is there  a way to sign without using privatekey ?

Comment: you can't sign without private key for some obvious security reason. You just want to send some sol from one account to another ? (why are you talking about usdc ?)

Comment: okay , can I use  receiver private key to sign  is that correct ?

Comment: About the USDC - I want also to make transfer with USDC but that is not working too.

Comment: no you can't use receiver private key, and you don't need it. You just need sender private key. the code you have shown is nothing related to a sol transfer. check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68166964/how-can-you-transfer-sol-using-the-web3-js-sdk-for-solana
but it is not clear to me if you want to sign with phantom or with a private key in the code ?

Comment: `const DEMO_FROM_SECRET_KEY = new Uint8Array([
    37, 21, 197, 185, 105, 201, 212, 148, 164, 108, 251, 159, 174, 252, 43, 246,
    225, 156, 38, 203, 99, 42, 244, 73, 252, 143, 34, 239, 15, 222, 217, 91, 132,
    167, 105, 60, 17, 211, 120, 243, 197, 99, 113, 34, 76, 127, 190, 18, 91, 246,
    121, 93, 189, 55, 165, 129, 196, 104, 25, 157, 209, 168, 165, 149,
]);`
How  I can get this array ? If you can help me with this My question will be answered

Comment: when you create a new keypair with CLI, then it is saved in a json file in .config/solana/*.json, you can find this array there. But again, please provide some context about what you are trying to perform, because i'm pretty sure you're going in the wrong direction :)

Comment: I have  2 accounts   merchant and customer, I want to send solana and/or USDC  from customer account to merchant account.  I am using  Browser side application not node JS

Answer (score 1):

After your last explanation, this is how you should do it :

```
var transaction = new web3.Transaction().add(
        web3.SystemProgram.transfer({
            fromPubkey: from.publicKey, // <= get the public key from the customer wallet
            toPubkey: new PublicKey('the public key of the merchant'),
            lamports: web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL * how_many_sol,
        })
    );
```

then you have to make the user sign & send the transaction with his wallet. For this step, may be using solana wallt adapter is a good idea, it will make things easier

You absolutely do not need a private key in your code in order to perform what you want to achieve